# Getting a webserver to run Bash commands locally and output back to web page

Tags: c, input, server, localhost, output

I'm building an interactive web page so that a user can type a Bash command into the HTML page, click run and the output will display on the same page.

As of now my server can run commands if they are put into the search bar, but it doesn't work for piping or flags, just basic commands.

I'm looking for help understanding why `pexec.c` below provides no output, only a blank page.

```
**wrc-server.c**

    /*
    ** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
    */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <poll.h>

    #define PORT "3838"  // The port users will be connecting to

    #define BACKLOG 10     // How many pending connections queue will hold

    void sigchld_handler(int s)
    {
        (void)s; // Quiet unused variable warning

        // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
        int saved_errno = errno;

        while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

        errno = saved_errno;
    }


    // Get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
    void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
    {
        if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
            return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
        }

        return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
    }

    char *parse(char *command) {
        char * newCommand = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*35);
        newCommand = strtok(command, " ");
        newCommand = strtok(NULL, "/ ");

        return newCommand;
    }

    char * execution(char *command) {
        //printf("yo:%s\n", command);

        int piper[2];
        size_t len = 0;
        pipe(piper);
        char* output =  malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
        memset(output, '\0', 1000* sizeof(char));
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid != 0) // Parent
        {
            wait(NULL);
            close(piper[1]);
            int n = sizeof(output);

            // ----Rob Code
            struct pollfd * poll_fd = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
            poll_fd->fd = piper[0];
            poll_fd->events = POLLIN;

            //wait(NULL);
            //printf("done\n");
            //printf("AAA %s", output);
            if (poll(poll_fd, 1, 0) == 1) { // Pipe data check
                read(piper[0], output, 1000);
            }
            //printf("the command is %s\n", output);
            //read(&output, output, piper[0]);
            //printf("%s\n", piper[0]);
            //dup2(piper[1], 1);
            //close(0)
        }
        else {
            //dup2(piper[1], 1);
            //printf("run: %s", command);

            close(1);
            dup(piper[1]);
            //close(0);
            execlp(command, command, NULL);
            exit(1);
        }
        // dup2 execute and print it out in parent

        // if (*(commands+1) != NULL) // Redirect stdout as long as were not at the last row
        // {
        //     dup2(piper[1], 1);
        //     close(piper[0]);
        // }
        return output;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int sockfd, new_fd;  // Listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // Connector's address information
        socklen_t sin_size;
        struct sigaction sa;
        int yes = 1;
        char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        int rv;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            return 1;
        }

        // Loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
            if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                 p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {

                perror("server: socket");
                continue;
            }

            if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                           sizeof(int)) == -1) {

                perror("setsockopt");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                close(sockfd);
                perror("server: bind");
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        //printf("%s\n", servinfo.ai_canonname);
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // All done with this structure

        if (p == NULL)  {
            fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");
        int ptds[2];
        char *commands = malloc(sizeof(char)*1212);
        while(1) { // Main accept() loop
            sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
            new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
            if (new_fd == -1) {
                perror("accept");
                continue;
            }

            inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                      get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                      s, sizeof s);
            printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

            char *buf = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));

            memset(buf, '\0', 1000* sizeof(char));

            recv(new_fd, buf, 1000*sizeof(char), 0);
            //printf("%s\n", parse(buf));

            ;

            if (!fork()) { // This is the child process
                close(sockfd); // Child doesn't need the listener

                if (send(new_fd, execution(parse(buf)), 1000, 0) == -1)
                    perror("send");
                close(new_fd);
                exit(0);
            }
            close(new_fd);
        }
        return 0;
    }

**pexec.c**

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    static char* args[512];
    pid_t pid;
    int command_pipe[2];

    #define READ  0
    #define WRITE 1

    static int command(int input, int first, int last)
    {
        int pipettes[2];

        pipe(pipettes);
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            if (first == 1 && last == 0 && input == 0) {
                // First command
                dup2(pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
            } else if (first == 0 && last == 0 && input != 0) {
                // Middle command
                dup2(input, STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
            } else {
                // Last command
                dup2(input, STDIN_FILENO);
            }

            if (execvp( args[0], args) == -1)
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (input != 0)
            close(input);

        close(pipettes[WRITE]);

        if (last == 1)
            close(pipettes[READ]);

        return pipettes[READ];
    }

    static void cleanup(int n)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            wait(NULL);
    }

    static int run(char* cmd, int input, int first, int last);
    static char line[1024];
    static int n = 0; /* Number of calls to 'command' */

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        while (1) {

            //  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            //     strcat(line, argv[i]);
            //     strcat(line, " ");
            // }

            /* Read a command line */
            //if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
                //return 0;
            int InputLength = atoi(getenv("INPUT_LENGTH"));
            fread(line, InputLength, 1, stdin);

            int input = 0;
            int first = 1;

            char* cmd = line;
            char* next = strchr(cmd, '@'); /* Find first '|' */

            while (next != NULL) {
                /* 'next' points to '|' */
                *next = '\0';
                input = run(cmd, input, first, 0);

                cmd = next + 1;
                next = strchr(cmd, '@'); /* Find next '|' */
                first = 0;
            }
            input = run(cmd, input, first, 1);
            cleanup(n);
            n = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void split(char* cmd);

    static int run(char* cmd, int input, int first, int last)
    {
        split(cmd);
        if (args[0] != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)
                exit(0);
            n += 1;
            return command(input, first, last);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static char* skipwhite(char* s)
    {
        while (isspace(*s))
            ++s;
        return s;
    }

    static void split(char* cmd)
    {
        cmd = skipwhite(cmd);
        char* next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
        int i = 0;

        while (next != NULL) {
            next[0] = '\0';
            args[i] = cmd;
            ++i;
            cmd = skipwhite(next + 1);
            next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
        }

        if (cmd[0] != '\0') {
            args[i] = cmd;
            next = strchr(cmd, '\n');
            next[0] = '\0';
            ++i;
        }

        args[i] = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Will do i apologize, Knew it was a lot of code but figured it would be fit

Comment: Simplified description and title

Comment: @BretHasel if you want to use pipes and other kinds of shell redirections why don't you just use the good old `system` from standard libc?

Comment: As per required i need to do it with execvp